# How to set up a project so that break points can be set in an attached process

Tags: visual-studio, process, localhost

I have started a local host application and I attached a project in visual studio to this iexplorer process what was running the app.  But I am unable to set break points in the code. I have tried to set break points but the errors says:

"This breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have  been loaded for this document."

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to attach it to the w3wp process, not the iexplorer or any browser process.